# Heroku run rake db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I did the following steps for deploying app and migrating my database:

```
  git add -A
  git commit -m "add changes"
  git push heroku master
  heroku run rake db:migrate
```

In console I see next:

```
  Running `rake db:migrate` attached to terminal... up, run.9234      
  == 20150713191218 CreateMovies: migrating       =================
  -- create_table(:movies)
  -> 0.0379s
  == 20150713191218 CreateMovies: migrated (0.0381s)  ============

   heroku restart
```

But `heroku run rake db:migrate` does not work. When I run my app, my database is empty. I don't understand why. I don't see any errors. 
And I'm sorry, that I repeat this question. I saw that people already asked about this problem, but no advice helped me.

Comment: Migrations only create the database table; they don't insert any data into the database. You'll need to do that separately.

Comment: It's normal, it should be empty, i. e. containing defined tables with no rows inside. What are you expecting instead? On top of that, it should run migrations automatically as part of deployment process initiated by `git push heroku master`, running it manually is normally a [no-op](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/no-op).

Comment: You are right.  I didn't understand correctly.

Answer (score 1):

try `heroku run rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production`

Answer (score 0):

To populate your database automatically with rake task you need to use the command `RAILS_ENV=production rake db:seed`(this will populate your production database) and have a seed file in place. But I guess that was not really what you were looking for